# Embedded links are not getting opened in Windows 8

Tags: java, windows-8, outlook, jakarta-mail

I have embedded an inline link for attachment using below code in JavaMail:

```
MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(attachFile); 
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID","file"); 
messageBodyPart.setFileName(attachFileName);
<a href='cid:html'>link text</a>
```

The above link is working fine Windows 8.1 & Windows 7 and attachment is getting opened within default application.

But in Windows 8 this link is not getting opened.
Please help into this.